# Cannot view contents of spoilers from user activity history on Teams sites

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams, spoilers

When expanding the contents of a new question or answer from the "All actions" subtab of a user profile on a Stack Overflow for Teams site, and that post contains a spoiler, I'm unable to view the contents of that spoiler: the text isn't shown when I click on the block.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a post that contains a spoiler.
2. Go to the user profile of the post's author, go to its Activity tab, and its "All actions" subtab.
3. Find the page containing the activity entry for asking or answering the post you found in step 1. (Filtering the list to "Posts" makes this easier, but isn't necessary to reproduce.) Expand this entry.
4. Attempt to click on the spoiler block. Nothing happens; the text isn't revealed.

Here's a screenshot. Clicking on the gray block (the spoiler) will not reveal the hidden text contained in it:

> [image: Spoiler block not revealed]

I'll add that it works just fine on public Q&A sites: clicking the spoiler block will reveal the text in it. It *only* seems to break on Stack Overflow for Teams sites.

I also checked my Developer Tools for console errors and there are none.